# Лишняя секунда в конце аудио

Tags: javascript, html, аудио, firefox

Подключаю как обычно аудио:

```html
<audio controls ${(this.props.autoplay && 'autoplay') || ''}>
  <source src="${this.props.src}" type="audio/wav">
  <source src="${this.props.src}" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="${this.props.src}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

И всё хорошо, кроме того что показывает длительность аудио `9:59`, но когда аудио завершается то это время вместе с уже прошедшим временем превращаются в 10 минут. Т.е. вот слушаешь аудио и всё время видишь `xx:xx/9:59`, а в самом конце показывается `9:59/9:59`, а потом превращается `10:00/10:00`. Сразу скажу, что проблема только в FF, в Chrome показывается всегда `9:59`

Пробовал тут в "Фрагмент кода" вставлять и просиходит тоже самое. К сожалению с самим файлом не могу поделиться, авторские права и т.д., но с другими файлами такого не просиходит

При отслеживании длины аудио такая же магия просиходит всё время показывает `599.134167`, а после окончания хоп и показывает `600.02234`. По экспериментам я так понял, что сайт или стили не виноваты. Пробовал следить за продолжительностью на других сайтах, других аудио и у них всё нормально - одно и то же число в начале и в конце. Возможно файл сам какой-то странный, других причин не нашёл. Сам файл формата `mp3`, так же пытался убрать `autoplay` и `source`-ы для `wav` и `ogg` - бесполезно. Скорее всего не важно, но так же пробовал не как строчку вставлять `audio`, а через `document.createElement('audio')` - тот же результат

Не могу понять, как с этим бороться. Меня устроит любой вариант, хоть пусть всегда показывает `9:59` хоть пусть показывает `10:00`, главное чтобы было одно время всегда

Comment: Подозреваю, что проблема на самом деле в кривом mp3-файле, который не содержит в себе информацию о длительности самого себя. Гугл подсказывает, что его можно попытаться починить через какой-то MP3Val, но это не точно (лично не пробовал)

Comment: @andreymal так и думал, что проблема в самом файле. К самому файлу у меня доступа нет, получаю его по ссылке. Но я думал, если проблема в самом файле, то и другие браузеры должны стардать этим. Видимо они (как минимум Chrome) более умные чем FF)

Answer (score 0):

У аудиофайлов бывает, что реальная продолжительность не соответствует той, что значится в заголовке файла. Попробуйте открыть файл в каком-то десктопном аудиоредакторе типа **Soundforge**, **Wavelab** или т. п. Потом опять сохранить. Если открывается нормально, т. е. появляется волновой график аулиофайла, можно потом правильно сохранить средствами этого редактора. Возможно, эта лишняя секунда на графике будет отображаться в виде горизонтальной линии тишины и весь фрагмент с этой линией можно будет из файла вырезать и потом сохранить.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! Но к сожалению, я не имею доступа к файлу, чтобы его чинить, так бы я с радостью) Если есть возможность решить проблему посредством самого JS, то буду сам менять, иначе я тут бессилен и надо обращаться к контент эдиторам. Просто хотел убедиться, что я точно бессилен со своей стороны :)

Comment: А плеер стандартный или кастомный? В случае кастомного это можно решить с помощью JS.

Comment: Самый обычный `audio` тег, как в коде что я приложил

Comment: Тогда не хотите сделать кастомный? Там можно будет запретить изменения вывода времени после окончания воспроизведения.

Comment: У нас уже был кастомный, но руководство решило что он не нужен и будем использовать встроенные плееры :)